# How to inject class with passing into it some argument

Tags: magento2, di

When we are injecting some class into another using constructor we are making this:

```
protected $someClass

public function __construct(SomeClass $someClass)
{
    $this->someClass = $someClass;
}
```

But what if we need to pass some argument into this `SomeClass`?

Magento has following implementation:

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList

```
$this->filters = [
    $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
];
```

I wan't to inject my own filter into plugin and pass into it `['layer' => $layer]`

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\Filter\Example">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="layer" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\Example</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

This class  Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\Filter\Example should extends `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter` 
You can see more here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Layer/FilterList.php#L39
Class Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\Example should extends `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer`

So you can pass argument `layer` class to class Filter\Example